# Identify unique and duplicate data in multiple rows across three columns

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have the following data:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
AA        AC        AD
AC        BK        DD
AA        AC        AD
CC        CA        CA
CC        BA        CC
```

I need a formula to identify Row 1 and Row 3 as duplicates, without adding an additional column.

I have already tried concatenating Columns A, B and C and then using COUNTIF to identify duplicates, but I do not want an additional column.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

With a formula and without access to another column certainly cuts down on the options, but I think possible.

Select ColumnsA:C and apply a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1
```

with formatting of your choice. That formatting should distinguish the relevant cells (provided not the same formatting as applied elsewhere).